# Separar valores de cada array

Tags: php, array

Bom dia Pessoal, tudo bem?
Tenho o codigo que imprime os valores diferentes encontrados em 2 arrays e esses valores ficam guardado na variavel diferentes ($diferentes)
Preciso saber como posso imprimir esses valores guardados em diferentes mas informando a qual array ele pertence:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [2,4,6,7];
$diferentes = 1, 3, 5, 7
```

Preciso imprimir:

```
$a = 1,3,5
$b = 7
```

Tentei usar `array_diff` mas sem êxito.

```
$diff1 = array_diff($diferentes, $a); 
$diff2 = array_diff($diferentes, $b);
```

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 10):

Uma possível solução seria ver quais são comuns, e extrair do resto:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [2,4,6,7];

$common = array_intersect( $b, $a ); 

$diff1 = array_diff( $a, $common );
$diff2 = array_diff( $b, $common );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/TwiP9e)**.

Mas se for só a separação que vc quer, e não for usar os membros comuns para nada, a solução mais simples é a do @Gabriel Rodrigues.

Comment: Então, mas eu preciso pegar a variavel $diferentes e saber quais numeros que estão nela são de seus respectivos arrays.

Comment: Consegui, como você disse, estava complicando coisa simples! Muito obrigado Bacco

Comment: Precisando, disponha. Fica como sugestão nas próximas perguntas você colocar como vai usar os dados. Aí pode ser que a gente consiga ajudar melhor.

Comment: Na próxima coloco o codigo que fiz e os dados que tenho, pra maior entendimento! Abração

Comment: @GustavoFreire recomendo passar a aceitação pra outra resposta.

Comment: Bacco, desculpa incomodar! Gostaria de saber se consigo fazer um exe desse codigo, onde $a seria Credito e $b seria Debito, pra pessoa entrar com valores em cada um, depois mandar executar e imprimir em um .txt o resultado. Obrigado

Comment: @GustavoFreire você pode rodar o PHP pelo console, (caminho onde o php está instalado)/php.exe meuscript.php

Comment: Bom dia Bacco, rodo pelo ideone.com , o que gostaria de saber, é uma luz de como poderia estar fazendo uma interface para usuario, onde ele entre com Valores de Credito e Valores de Debito, e o codigo php faria a comparação. Obrigado ple atenção

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38014/discussion-between-gustavo-freire-and-bacco).

Answer (score 2):

Na realidade seria assim:

Utilizando o seu array de Exemplo:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [2,4,6,7];
```

Se você deseja  a diferença de `$b` em relação ao `$a` fará:

```
$diff1 = array_diff($b, $a);
```

Que resultará em:

```
array (size=2)
  2 => int 6
  3 => int 7
```

Sendo 6 e 7 a diferença por que eles não existem em `$a`.

Agora se deseja a diferença de `$a` em relação ao `$b` fará:

```
$diff2 = array_diff($a,$b);
```

Que resultará em:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 1
  2 => int 3
  4 => int 5
```

Sendo 1,3 e 5 a diferença por que eles não existem em `$b`.